# Post values from table in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a table:

```
    <table id="selectedInv">
        <thead>
            <tr class="alternate">
                <th>
                    Barcode
                </th>
                <th>
                    OverAll Count
                </th>
                <th>
                    Transfer Count
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr class="1">
                <td> 2323 </td><td> 9 </td><td><input type="text" value="3"></td></tr>
           <tr class="2">
                <td> 2329 </td><td> 5 </td><td><input type="text" value="2"></td></tr>
           <tr class="3">
                <td> 2329 </td><td> 3 </td><td><input type="text" value="1"></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

After button click I want to collect data like

> [{1,3},{2,2},{3,1}]

Where in

> [{a,b}] a=className of row, b=input text value in this row.

And post this data to action method, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: before asking what's the best way, show us a way you tried...

Comment: I know, I can iterate table, a collect Data. but how to pass this data to asp.net mvc action Method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i see u have two fields to collect data from each row namely Class and Transfer count. i would make a view model for it like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int CodeClass{get;set;} //class is reserved word
    public int TransferCount{get;set;}
}
```

In my view i would write a loop that creates following html

```
<table id="selectedInv">
        <thead>
            <tr class="alternate">
                <th>
                    Barkod
                </th>
                <th>
                    OverAll Count
                </th>
                <th>
                    Transfer Count
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr class="1">
                <td> 2323 </td><td> 9 </td><td><input name="data[0].TransferCount" type="text" value="3"><input type="hidden" value = "1" name = "data[0].CodeClass"/></td></tr>
           <tr class="2">
                <td> 2329 </td><td> 5 </td><td><input type="text" value="2" name="data[1].TransferCount"><input type="hidden" value = "1" name = "data[1].CodeClass"/></td></tr>
           <tr class="3">
                <td> 2329 </td><td> 3 </td><td><input type="text" value="1" name="data[2].TransferCount"><input type="hidden" value = "1" name = "data[2].CodeClass"/></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

supposing that you are posting the form to index method. it would look like

```
public ActionResult index(IEnumerable<ViewModel> data)
{
 //do something with data
}
```

don't forget the submit button to post the form. For more information read [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)
Following [search](https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?rlz=1C1_____enPK456PK456&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=uh&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1_____enPK456PK456&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=modelbinding%20to%20list%20asp.net%20mvc&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=4a9852210d308dea&ix=uh&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=667) would also prove good for you

Comment: name attributes are important in mvc model binding